# Computing FIRST and FOLLOW

Tags: formal-languages, compilers, parsers

Given the following grammar with terminals $VT=\{[,],a,b,c,+,-\}:$

> $S \rightarrow [SX]|a$
>
> $X \rightarrow +SY|Yb|\epsilon$
>
> $Y \rightarrow -SXc|\epsilon$

This should be the FIRST function:

> $first(S) = \{[,a\}$
>
> $first(X) = \{\epsilon,+,-,b\}$
>
> $first(Y) = \{\epsilon,-\}$

What would the FOLLOW function be?

Comment: There is an algorithm for computing the FOLLOW function. All you have to do is run it, manually or on a computer. It is even likely that people have already programmed this, and you can use their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the FOLLOW function:

> $follow(S) = \{\$,+,-,b,],c\}$
>
> $follow(X) = \{],c\}$
>
> $follow(Y) = \{b,],c\}$